# how to subtract dates in twig?

Tags: twig

```
{%for mat in setQuery %}
   {% set datePost = mat.data_criacao|date('d-m-Y') %}
   {% set today = "now"|date('d-m-Y') %}
   {{today- datePost}}
{% endfor %}
```

datePost = 17-04-2015
today = 06-05-2015

the example above returns it: -11

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The issue was resolved with the following code:

```
{% set datePost = mat.data_criacao|date('d-m-Y') %}
{% set today = "now"|date('d-m-Y') %}
{% set difference = date(today).diff(date(datePost))%}
{% set leftDays = difference.days %}
{% if datePost == today %}
      1 day
{% else %}
    {{ leftDays }}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thank you! It's great to see a solution that works with just the built-in tools. Personally, I'd have picked this as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

**You must write your custom twig extension:**

You must write a twig function as described [here](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/advanced.html#functions) with the following code for make diff via php function:

```
$calcFrom = $from;

$calcTo = $to;
$now->diff($calcFrom)->format("%a")
```

And make it available via a [Twig extension](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html).

If you are using symfony2 framework You can use the [KnpTimeBundle](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpTimeBundle)

In the Twig:
This compare with the current date:

```
{# Returns something like "3 minutes ago" #}
{{ time_diff(form) }}
```

This compare with the another date:

```
{# Returns something like "3 minutes ago" #}
{{ time_diff(form , to ) }}
```

Hope this help